# trying to create div from mysql database

Tags: php

Im trying to create a div from rows in a mysql database, but when I loop through the database table and apply the returned rows to the div, I only get back the last row. Here is the code :

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "divs";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "setdivs";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * from getinfo";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo " <div id=\"vertical-with-linking\" class=\"fn-container fn-vertical\"         style=\"color: rgb(51, 51, 51); margin: 0px auto; overflow: hidden; position:  relative; width: 580px; height: 280px\">";

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "<br> id: ". $row["id"]. " - Name: ". $row["divtitle"]. " " .   $row["datalink"] . "<br>";// works fine

        //echo "<div title = " . $row['divtitle'] . " data-link: " .  $row['datalink'] . "><img src=" . $row['imagesrc'] . " />";//returns last row only
    }
 } else {
    echo "0 results";
 }

 $conn->close();
?>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried with Firebug or similar tool to check if the divs are there but not displaying (cause of css or something...)?

Answer (score 1):

This is a safer way. You had no quotes around the attribute values and if any, like `$row['divtitle']` have spaces in them then they must be quoted with either double quotes or single quotes.

Also it should be `data-link=` and not `data-link:`

And you need to close the div after the img tag is completed

```
echo "<div title='{$row['divtitle']}' data-link='{$row['datalink']}'><img src='{$row['imagesrc']}'/></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should close the div

```
echo "<div title = " . $row['divtitle'] . " data-link: " .  $row['datalink'] . "><img src=" . $row['imagesrc'] . " />";//returns last row only
```

to

```
echo "<div title = " . $row['divtitle'] . " data-link: " .  $row['datalink'] . "><img src=" . $row['imagesrc'] . " /></div>";//returns last row only
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that your Div's are not closed.

try this.

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "divs";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "setdivs";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * from getinfo";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo " <div id=\"vertical-with-linking\" class=\"fn-container fn-vertical\"         style=\"color: rgb(51, 51, 51); margin: 0px auto; overflow: hidden; position:  relative; width: 580px; height: 280px\">";

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "<br> id: ". $row["id"]. " - Name: ". $row["divtitle"]. " " .   $row["datalink"] . "<br>";// works fine

        echo "<div title = " . $row['divtitle'] . " data-link= " .  $row['datalink'] . "><img src=" . $row['imagesrc'] . " /></div>";//returns last row only
    }

    echo "</div>";
 } else {
    echo "0 results";
 }

 $conn->close();
?>
```